# Reject all Microsoft Office attachments

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-office, smtp, exim

I have had enough of spam coming to my server with Microsoft Office attachments. No one I care about ever sends me Microsoft Office documents so I would like to reject (with a polite message) all email with Microsoft Office documents attached.

I tried this:

```
  # Reject messages that have serious MIME errors.
  #
  deny
    message     = Serious MIME defect detected ($demime_reason)
    demime      = *
    condition   = ${if >{$demime_errorlevel}{2}{1}{0}}


  # Unpack MIME containers and reject file extensions used by worms.
  # This calls the demime condition again, but it will return cached results.
  # Note that the extension list may be incomplete.
  #
  deny
    message     = We do not accept ".$found_extension" attachments here.
    demime      = bat:btm:cmd:com:cpl:dll:exe:lnk:msi:pif:prf:reg:scr:vbs:url
```

I get this error: `cannot test demime condition in RCPT ACL`.

Comment: After [researching](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=37728) this topic, and attempting what you discovered, what have you tried exactly?

Comment: I do not want to have to mess with filters. That's right out. ACLs seem to be best bet but I could not find the right documentation. It's been ages since I messed with Exim configurations.  A quick Google search did not yield anything of use.  Hence the question.

Comment: Please give it a try and update the question with your attempt... it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following works:

```
 # Reject known virus spreading file extensions.
 # Accepting these is pretty much braindead.
 deny
   message = contains $found_extension file (blacklisted).
   demime  = doc:docx:xls:xlsx
```

[Source](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-content_scanning_at_acl_time.html).